# Data display on two screen simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app there is a side menu and main home screen,

[image]

Data come from web service and it return JSON object,

In JSON object category like 1,2,3,4.... and its related description like image and price etc. are come.

it was called `ViewDidLoad` of side menu class first and then called home screen class so i called my web service in side menu class using `NSURLConnection` object.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSString *url_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl.php"];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:url_str];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [response_data appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [response_data setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection :(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR WITH CONNECTION");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *myError;
    table_data=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response_data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
    NSLog(@"JSON data  %@",table_data);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Response data comes properly but after home `ViewDidLoad` method.so i am not able to get data for home screen.

Any one can help me how can i display data simultaneously on both screen after getting response of web service.

Comment: Have you tried to use the delegation protocol? Side menu would be delegate of the main screen, and when you get the data, you can call a method on the main screen to update it.

Comment: @TiagoLira : thank you replaying but i dont have any idea..can u please guide me?? how can i solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple places you want to have the UI respond (ie. by displaying the results of the loaded data) when an operation has completed, you can use NSNotificationCenter to broadcast a notification.

In your connectionDidFinishLoading method, you would want to send a notification like this:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *myError;
    table_data=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response_data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
    NSLog(@"JSON data  %@",table_data);
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:table_data forKey:@"table_data"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"DataLoadedNotification" 
        object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

}
```

In your home screen, you can listen for the notification and re-draw the data on the screen by doing something like this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveDataLoadNotification:) 
    name:@"DataLoadedNotification"
    object:nil];
```

Of course, you need to implement the method that will get called when the notification is received:

```
- (void) receiveDataLoadNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // [notification name] should always be @"DataLoadedNotification"
    // unless you use this method for observation of other notifications
    // as well.

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"DataLoadedNotification"])
    {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        JSONObject *table_data = [userInfo objectForKey:@"table_data"];
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the data loaded notification!");
    }
}
```

If you need to, you can pull the table_data object